# Custom page URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm converting an old website usign a Wordpress like a CMS.

I'm creating pages, but all pages are created on `http://domain/page-permalink` and I need it on `http://domain/category/page-permalink`

Pages can't containt categories, so I don't know how to clone old URL structure.

There is a way to to this ? I need to create URLs of pages like `category/page-permalink` because I need to have the 'category' to show specific menus and images.

I can use different templates for evcery category pages, but still need to use a personaliced URL which include the category.

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a custom taxonomy to your pages.

This will register a taxonomy on pages, put this code in a function that is in an after_setup_theme add_action:

```
register_taxonomy('pagecats',array (
  0 => 'page',
),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Page Categories','show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'rewrite' => true,'singular_label' => 'Page Category') );
```

Comment: And, how can I add this taxonomy on the URL ? http://domain/taxonomy/page-permalink ?

Comment: Setting `'rewrite' => true` will automatically add `'pagecats'` (or whatever you filed in there) to the WordPress permalink system. For a more detailed explanation check http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks

Answer (score 0):

If you configure [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) it will allow you to customize the permalink structure. This is the way I put sub-directories in my URL.